# how to attach any function parameter to out put list in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and using function capability of python for the very first time. I have written thr codes like:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        chunk = l[i:i+n]
        G = chunk.count('G')
        C = chunk.count('C')
        A = chunk.count('A')
        T = chunk.count('T')
        G_C = G+C
        Total_G_C_A_T = G_C+A+T
        G_C_contents = ((G_C) / float(Total_G_C_A_T))*100
        GC_Window100.append(G_C_contents)
    print (GC_Window100)
chunks (list3, 100)
chunks (list3, 150)
chunks (list3, 200)
```

My question is: How I can attach the value of n with list for that calculation? Like I am using GC_Window100, I want 100 should come from function parameter so that I can keep track of list, from which chunk it came from. I need to repeat this function several time. 
and output I want like:

GC_Window100 = [30, 32, 31, 42]

GC_Window150 = [18, 20, 22, 20]

GC_Window200 = [15, 13, 16, 10]
.
.
.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want n to increment in the for loop ?? or do you wanna use it inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but this is a simple enough approach.

```
tracked_responses = []
tracked_responses.append(chunks(list3, 100))
```

Then in your `chunks` function, you return a tuple like this

```
return (n, CS_Window100)
```

Now your tracked_responses is a list of tuples with the input for `n` as the first element, and the CS_Window100 value as the second.

At that point, it would probably make sense to rename your function variable to CS_Window instead of CS_Window100.

Your tracked_responses would look something like this:

```
[(100, [1.2, 1.4, 45.4]), (200, [5.4, 3.4, 1.0]), ...]
```

If you needed to access by the value of `n`, then you can cast this list of tuples to a dictionary and access like so.

```
tracked_responses_dict = dict(tracked_responses)
print tracked_responses_dict[100]
```

**Since you are new to Python**

Here is something you can do to tidy up your code.

1. Use collections.counter

Collections.counter is a nice way to group and assign counts to unique items in a iterable (like a list).

```
gcat_counts = collections.counter(chunk)
g_c = gcat_counts.get('G', 0) + gcat_counts.get('C', 0)
a_t = gcat_counts.get('A', 0) + gcat_counts.get('T', 0)
```

Using the get method will ensure you get some value, even if the key does not exist.

**So a revised script might look like this**

```
import collections

def chunks(l, n):
    gc_window = []
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        chunk = l[i:i + n]
        gcat_counts = collections.counter(chunk)
        g_c = gcat_counts.get('G', 0) + gcat_counts.get('C', 0)
        a_t = gcat_counts.get('A', 0) + gcat_counts.get('T', 0)
        total_gcat = g_c + a_t
        g_c_contents = (g_c / float(total_gcat)) * 100
        gc_window.append(g_c_contents)
    return (n, gc_window)

tracked_responses = []
tracked_responses.append(chunks(list3, 100))
tracked_responses.append(chunks(list3, 150))
tracked_responses.append(chunks(list3, 200))

tracked_responses_dict = dict(tracked_responses)
print tracked_responses_dict[100]
```